# Why Django server with Docker is running without database in postgresql?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x, docker

I wonder why my server is running and why it doesn't see another database. To wit `psql` and `\l`:

```
                                    List of databases
    Name     |    Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-------------+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 aso         | postgres    | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0   | postgres    | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
             |             |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1   | postgres    | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
             |             |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 owner       | owner       | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
(4 rows)
```

My Django settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

As you can see there is no database named `postgres` but server is running properly (save data etc.). On the other hand when I use:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'aso',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

I get `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "aso" does not exist`
Can anyone explain me this?

**EDITED**
@Adaikalaraj advised to create database in docker. I'm trying in this way:

`init.sql`:

```
CREATE USER postgres;
CREATE DATABASE aso;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE aso TO postgres;
```

My updated `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6.1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
FROM library/postgres
ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
db_1   | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-07-05 14:02:41 UTC
web_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 145: exec: python3: not found
db_1   | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1   | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1   | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
dockerpri_web_1 exited with code 127
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `'HOST': 'db'` is running inside docker, Seems you are checking `psql` in your system. Either you can give your IP adress (eg: 127.0.0.1) in `HOST : 127.0.0.1` or you can create the db `aso` in the postgres running inside docker.

Comment: I would like to create database in docker because in the future I would like to deploy my project with database on Heroku. How can I do this?

Comment: You can add the following in your Docker file
      `FROM library/postgres`
      `ENV POSTGRES_USER docker`
      `ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD docker`
      `ENV POSTGRES_DB docker`

Comment: I have edited my Dockerfile (I added to first post) but still the same error.

Comment: I'm trying to create database in docker using init.sql file but it seems doesn't working. I have updated my first post.